# Execute function on third party function return

Tags: javascript

i need to "detect" when some third party function returns and then execute my own function.

example: some function i didn't write

```
function foo(params1){
  console.log(params1);
}
```

my function:

```
function bar(params2){
  console.log(params2);
}
```

i need that whenever `foo` is called, it somehow calls `bar` immediately !
i tried going this way:

```
foo = function(params1){
  console.log(params1);
  bar(params2);
}
```

meaning i "overwrite" `foo` .. but sometimes (always), `foo` code is too lengthy + passing `params2` (minor) problem.
I tried desperate attempts with prototype and so .. but then i figured i need some support on this.

i also tried this: (but)

```
var tmp = foo;
foo = function(params1) {
  tmp(params1);
  bar(params2);
}
```

Same problem here, the caller will call `foo(params1)` thus bar won't "find" `params2`.

---

I need this to make something like an "event handler".
The third party function makes some ajax calls, acts on the DOM, i immediately take action.
Is there a neat way of doing this? i hope this is interesting. Thanks.
ps: i though about making `params2` global, but i still need an "original" solution :)

As for the use of `params2`, let's say i want to use different params for every function i want to hook.

examples:

```
var tmp = foo_1;
foo_1 = function(params1) {
  tmp(params1);
  bar(params2);
}

tmp = foo_2;
foo_2 = function(params1) {
  tmp(params1);
  bar(params3);
}
//etc..
```

Comment: How can `foo` know what are the params for `bar`, event in your last example. Where the params for `bar`came from?

Comment: that's the problem. when i said it worked i was using global variables not params 2 (i edited) sorry

Comment: What is `params2`?  Where does it come from?  Is it derived from `params1`?  Is it in a global?  Is it in an object somewhere?  Is it always the same so you can code it into the function?

Comment: it is not always the same, i want it different for each function i hook
so params2 for foo, params3 for foo_2 .. etc .. (edited my question)

Comment: @UnLoCo - Your edit isn't answering the question we've posed.  You can't just say the params are different every time.  You have to tell us how you determine what they are or where they come from.  This is a program.  It needs an algorithm that determine what the parameters to bar are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use a simple [pubSub](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS) system to get notified when foo is called. This will decouple your call of `bar` from `foo`.

```
(function(){
  var footmp = foo;

   foo = function(){
     var result = footmp.apply(this, arguments);
     PubSub.publish('fireBar');
     return result;
  }
})()

PubSub.subscribe( 'fireBar', function(){
 // try to figure out whats params2
 bar(params2)
} );
```

Comment: but this would call 'bar' before 'foo' has returned, am i right ?
i need like an immediate chain ! :)

Comment: i was hoping for a lighter solution but this would solve it. you gave me a good idea. i could use a proxy function and give it a parameter for each function, and the latter would call the function bar .. with no need for pubsub,i guess. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If `foo` is a global function, you can hook it like this using [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments):

```
var oldFoo = foo;
foo = function() {
    // call oldFoo with whatever arguments were passed
    var returnVal = oldFoo.apply(this, arguments);

    // do your thing
    bar(params2);

    // if oldFoo had a returned value, return it here
    return(returnVal);
}
```

You can do your work either before or after you call the original.  [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) allow you to pass the original arguments (whatever they were) onto `foo` without you even having to know what they were.

In your code example you don't say where `params2` come from so it's hard for us to know how to inject them in.  You can extract them from the original arguments passed to `foo`, you can build them into the function or retrieve them from some object.

These are your options for figuring out what `params2` should be and passing them appropriately to `bar()`:

1. **Derive them from the arguments passed to `foo`.**  Either you pass the same arguments to `bar` or you look at the arguments that were passed to `foo` and you create the arguments for `bar` from those.
2. **Make them the same thing every time.**  You just code this into the new function.  It sounds like this is not what you want.
3. Before `foo` gets called, **put the desired arguments to `bar` in some sort of globally reachable variable** and then in your replacement function, you can fetch them from that global.
4. Before `foo` gets called, **put the desired arguments to `bar` in some sort of closure** so you can get them from the closure in your replacement function.

Comment: Its mostly the same as the last example which not work cause params2 is undefined.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle - The OP has to tell us where params2 comes from.  They've not told us what it is or where it comes from so there's no way we can guide on how to code it.  Where does it come from?  What is it?  Is it a global variable?  Is it derived from the arguments to `foo`?  Is it data in some global object?  What is it?  We can't read the OP's mind on how to code it if they don't tell us what it is or what it's supposed to be!

Comment: hey it's me who asked :) and sorry for that i will edit. thanks

Comment: @UnLoCo - I've updated my answer with four options for the arguments to `bar()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) to the function

```
var tmp = foo;
foo = function(params1) {
  tmp.apply(this, arguments);
  bar(params2);
}
```

Comment: Its the same as the last example which not work cause params2 is undefined.